# Is long running select locking updates on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a monitoring query for our admins that they run directly in the management studio. This query is a long running query that analyses all records in a table. We have noticed now that when this query is running incoming updates a blocked until this query is finished. After a little investigation we have seen that on sql server select does a shared lock that blocks exclusive locks and that an update does a update lock and then a exclusive lock.

https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/07/28/why-do-we-need-update-locks-in-sql-server/#comment-104367

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186396(v=sql.105)

Is this a behavior that we can change? What is the best practice to avoid this situation if we have a public portal as frontend where we have many selects also a little bit longer running and different updates on the same table?

Comment: Ideally you would improve the performance of your queries such that they are quick. However as a purely monitoring function you might decide you can get away without taking a shared lock using the query hint ` with (nolock)`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017. I would not recommend that approach for you public facing site queries - they need to be improved.

Comment: Did you try the snapshot isolation for long running select queries?

Comment: @DaleBurrell this means best practices to avoid locks of this kind is to have fast queries or to divide update statements and sql statements on different dbs?

Comment: @serge i have seen that on snapshot isolation have to be careful because the need extra space for the tempdb right?

Comment: Best practice is definitely to have fast queries :) However in cases where this isn't possible, e.g. reporting or similar, possible solutions are to run the query when the database isn't busy, run the query against a copy of database, have copy functions which build the report data, maybe to another database. I would suggest that analysing every record in a table is probably not something you want to do on a live database.

Comment: @cpiock in any DBMS the snapshot approach always requires more resources than locking one. If you're really starving the RAM/disk space and CPU this may be the limitation.

Comment: ok. thanks for your comments. helps me a lot for better evaluation of the problem.

Comment: does a select on a index view also a shared lock on the table behind? so it is possibile to to the read on index views and updates on the table it self? does this make sense?

Comment: If your index is a covering index, i.e. includes every column you are attempting to access, then there will be no lock applied at table level. There will be an index lock applied though, so if your update causes a change to the index you're still going to be waiting. For your monitoring I would be very tempted to use `with (nolock)` - at least in the short time while you implement a better solution.

Comment: thx @DaleBurrell for help